# Equality between two total derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

With one variable functions, I have, for $c$ and $k$ constants and $f,g$ functions of $x$,

$$\dfrac{df}{dx}=c\dfrac{dg}{dx}\Longrightarrow f=cg+k\Longrightarrow \dfrac{df}{dg}=c.$$

(By $df/dg$ I mean performing a variable change $y=g(x)$ and calculate $df/dy$.)

Is this also true for total derivatives, I mean,
$$\dfrac{df}{d\xi}=c\dfrac{d x_1}{d\xi}\Longrightarrow \dfrac{df}{d x_1}=c$$

if $\dfrac{df}{d\xi}, \dfrac{d x_1}{d\xi}$ are total derivatives, where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is function of $x_1,\cdots,x_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, which in turn are functions of $\xi$ (so, $\dfrac{df}{d \xi}$ is a total derivative).

I also have $\xi=y/z\in\mathbb{R}$, where $y,z\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you.

=================

Edit. I'd like to know if the following is correct:

Suppose $x_1$ is an invertible function of $\xi$ s.t. the inverse is derivable, I mean, there exists $d\xi/d(x_1)$. So, multiplying $\dfrac{df}{d\xi}=c\dfrac{d x_1}{d\xi}$ by $\dfrac{d \xi}{dx_1}$,

$$\dfrac{df}{d\xi}\dfrac{d \xi}{dx_1}=c,$$

i.e.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{d x_i}{d\xi}\dfrac{d \xi}{dx_1}=\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{d x_i}{dx_1}=\dfrac{d f}{d x_1}=c.$$

> Related:
> [Homogenous PDE, changing of variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919510/homogenous-pde-changing-of-variable)

Comment: What does $df/dg$ even mean? People write nonsense like this ...

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry by this... I mean the following: If I make a change of variable s.t. $y=g(x)$, so $df/dg=df/dy$. Thank you for attention, Mr. Shifrin.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I'll edit the question, maybe it can be better. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by inverse is derivable? What is $f$?

Comment: @Buraian, please, I've tried to edit, could you see again? Thank you!

Comment: Is $y=g(x)$ a valid change of variable when $g$ is not a one-to-one function?

Comment: @TedShifrin, I am sorry, ok, suppose this. Thank you so much.